# Как завершить другой поток без задержки?

Tags: c, linux

Есть поток, который периодически засыпает, просыпается, проверяет значение переменной, и если оно ложно, все повторяется, а если истинно, поток завершается. Выглядит это примерно так:

Cоздание потока:

```
context->exit = false;
pthread_create(thread, NULL, worker, context);
```

Завершение потока:

```
context->exit = true;    
pthread_join(thread, NULL);
```

Выполнение потока:

```
void *worker(void *context) {
    while (true) {
        if (context->exit)
            break;

        sleep(timeout);
    }
}
```

Когда флаг завершения exit устанавливается true, проходит некоторе время прежде, чем поток завершится. Как сделать так, чтобы поток завершился сразу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как завершить другой поток без задержки?

Первое что приходит в голову - не делать задержку. Надо не делать sleep, а использовать сигнальную переменную.

Выглядеть будет примерно так

```
void * worker(struct my_ctx *context) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&context->mylock);
    while (!context->exit) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&context->my_condition, &context->mylock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&context->mylock);

    return 0;
}
```

Тогда убивающий:

```
context->exit = true;   
pthread_mutex_lock(&context->mylock);
pthread_cond_signal(&context->my_condition);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&context->mylock);
pthread_join(thread, NULL);
```

Comment: Насколько я могу догадываться в вопросе предполагается, что worker() кроме sleep() что-то еще должен делать в цикле. Вопрос по Вашему примеру. Кто будет периодически посылать ему pthread_cond_signal(&context->my_condition); ?

Comment: Я не понял вопроса.. зачем периодически? Так организуйте жизненный цикл соответствующим образом и не нужно будет ничего слать. Я привёл пример просто как сделать ожидание некоего события.. возникновения флага выхода в данном случае. Это самый классический способ, который можно встретить где угодно, в том числе в Java или dotNET (выглядеть будет чуть иначе только).

Comment: Возможно я не правильно интерпретирую вопрос. Но мне кажется, что задача состоит в том, что thread в цикле что-то делает, потом какое-то время спит, опять делает и т.д. Собственно вопрос о прерывании паузы. Как это делать для потока ? Для процесса понятно - послать сигнал и sleep прервется. В Вашем ответе поток засыпает в pthread_cond_wait() на неопределенное время - пока pthread_cond_signal() кто-нибудь не вызовет. Или я не правильно интерпретирую суть вопроса @тимур ?

Comment: Ну так это от задачи зависит. Я же не телепат, чтобы знать, что worker делать должен. Если поток что-то вовсю делает, то он может периодически просто проверять флаг, а если он чего-то ждёт, то может использовать такой подход и по сигналу проверять и флаг выхода, и то событие, которое ожидает. Хотя, в вопросе чётко сказано, что "поток периодически ЗАСЫПАЕТ" и вопрос именно про sleep.

Comment: Вот и я о том же. И тоже не телепат. А разве сигнал будет прерывать syscall (для sleep видимо sigpause для SIGALRM) во всех потоках ? Насколько мне известно сигнал конкретному потоку послать нельзя.

Comment: Так не надо прерывать sleep, надо его не делать и в этом заключался ответ :D